# Compiling a C dll for 64 bits

Tags: c, xml, dll, visual-studio-2013, labview

My problem is about trying to compile a C dll and its dependency to 64bits and to use it in `LabVIEW`.

To start with the beginning, I'm using a 32 bit `LabVIEW` toolkit to use XML files ([downloaded from here](http://sourceforge.net/projects/labxml/files/LibXML-toolkit/) ). This toolkit is using 32 dll dlls that works fine (`libxml`, `libxslt`, `iconv`, `zlib`, and a wrapper `dll IXMLWrap`)

Now, I want to use it with 64 bits version of `LabVIEW`. The `LabVIEW` part of that migration should not be a problem, but first of all, I have to get 64 bits version of the dlls.
I [downloaded the 64 bits versions](ftp://ftp.zlatkovic.com/libxml/64bit/), except for `IXMLWrap` (specific one). But I have the `.c` file of that wrapper.

So I tried to compile it with visual studio, and successed ... almost !
I get a home compiled 64bit `IXMLWrap` dll, but impossible to load it with `LabVIEW` 64 bits...
When reading the dll with "`Dependency Walker`" 64bits, I get some errors about missing export functions.
Indeed, when I compare the 32 and 64 bits dlls with `Dependency Walker`, I do have the same functions in the dlls, but do not have the same exported functions ... (sorry I'd like to post images of that but not enough reputation...

Does someone have some hint about what is the problem with my `IXMLWrap dll` : incorrect downloaded dlls, problems in the configuration of my Visual studio project, ... ?

Comment: Exporting functions work by adding a VC specific macro in front of the function, that turn into __declspec(export) at compilation. Try to find something like this in the source, and add it to the functions that are not exported

Answer (score 1):

OK, it's all my fault...
I did the link with .lib files ... coming from linux (not windows)!!
No problems then to compile and use the 64bits dll